# Meteor HTTP get the cookie from the response

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor server side code sends a `HTTP.call` and needs to get the value of the cookie from the response header. I could not find clear doc showing how so I tried this which gave:

`console.log('response: %j', response.headers.set-cookie);`

> cookie is not defined

But there is a cookie in the response body which looks like this

`console.log('response: %j', response.headers);`

```
{
  "date": "Mon, 18 Apr 2016 23:18:58 GMT",
  "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "expires": "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT",
  "set-cookie": ["JSESSIONID=0000saKY2KAfxMD3sYcqgc8N11d:16poh0lr1; Path=/is"],
  "p3p": "CP=\"CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE\"",
  "keep-alive": "timeout=3, max=50",
  "connection": "Keep-Alive",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "content-type": "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1",
  "content-language": "en-US"
}
```

How can I get that tasty cookie out of the response header? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since minus sign can not be a part of JS variable name, the part `set-cookie` is treated as a subtraction operator, yielding an error since `cookie` variable is not defined. Use dictionary syntax instead.

```
response.headers['set-cookie']
```

Comment: Which is the exact value of the cookie? is it the value of `JSESSIONID` if so, with or without the "second" part after the ":"? thx

Comment: The syntax is `KEY=VALUE; KEY=VALUE; ...`, so the value of `JSESSIONID` is `0000saKY2KAfxMD3sYcqgc8N11d:16poh0lr1` and the value of `Path` is `/is`.